# Passport.deserlializeUser() security

Tags: node.js, http, security, mongoose, passport.js

I am using `Passport.js` for authentication in my Node.js application. I understand that the function `deserializeUser()`:

```
 passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
   User.findById(id, function (err, user) {
      if (user) done(err, user);
   });
 });
```

loads the user object in `req.user`and sends it along with every request the user makes. I am concerned however if it's secure to be sending the full user object with every HTTP request or if I should only select specific fields to send using `User.find().select()` from Mongoose. If yes, are there fields other than `req.user.id` that subsequent requests wouldn't work without or can I unselect all the other fields?

Comment: The `req` is not sent to client. It is in server. You can use `req.user` in the lifesycle of `req`.

Comment: Aha so the user has no access to the `req.user`. I probably just need to encrypt the data I am sending either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose what to keep while doing `serializeUser` and `deserializeUser`.

`SerializeUser` runs once after authentication stategy succeessfuly ran. And on every further requests, `deserializeUser` runs.

```
//send 'user' instead of 'user._id' or 'user.id' into 'done()' function.
passport.serializeUser(function(user,done)
{
    done(null,user);//this user is sent to 'deserializeUser'
});
```

while `deserializing` user, choose which `fields` to keep in `req.user`.

```
passport.deserializeUser(function(user,done)
{
    User.findById(user._id,function(err,user)
    {
        var currUser= {};
        currUser._id=user._id;
        //choose which fields to keep in req.user
        currUser.email=user.email;
        currUser.name = user.name;
        //currUser is what is saved in 'req.user'
        done(err,currUser);
    });
});
```

As @Ebrahim said, the data is not sent to client, it is on the server side only, and can be used for the life-cycle of `req`. So, you need not worry about vulnerable to interception. But, i think you should keep minimal data in `req.user`.

[PassportJs](http://passportjs.org) is one of the best Safe Authentication Resource as of now.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Okay but should I be concerned about that the data being sent might be vulnerable to interception and not send critical fields of a user or are my concerns invalid?

Comment: As Ebrahim said, the data is not sent to client, so you need not worry about vulnerable to interception. But, i think you should keep minimal data in `req.user`.